# How to deploy the corda-finance-3.1-corda.jar?

Tags: corda

Can someone tells me what to do in gradle file to produce *corda-finance-3.1-corda.jar* after running `gradlew deployNodes`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `finance` CorDapp to each node's CorDapps in `deployNodes`:

```
node {
    ...
    cordapps = ["$corda_release_group:corda-finance:$corda_release_version"]
    ...
}
```

See the example here: https://github.com/corda/cordapp-example/blob/release-V3/kotlin-source/build.gradle#L115.